# Custom exception for ORA01400 not working

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, triggers

I'm doing a school assignment where I have to add exceptions in all PL/SQL. Since I've created some sequences and triggers to add auto-increment functionality (this is Oracle SQL), I thought I'd add an exception to all triggers concerning `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into(...)`.

Following the [example here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Exception), I've created a package to store my custom exception, so I can use it in all triggers that implement the auto-incrementation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_exceptions
AS
    insert_null_into_notnull EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(insert_null_into_notnull, -1400);
END my_exceptions;
/
```

This is one of the triggers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_cust_id
BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT pk_cust_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.CUST_ID FROM DUAL;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN my_exceptions.insert_null_into_notnull THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Attempted to insert a null value into not nullable column.');
        RAISE;
END;
/
```

The problem is when I try to add a failed insert on purpose, I still get the typical Oracle error as: `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (...)` rather than the DBMS_OUTPUT that I wanted.

I've looked at the example on the website a few times and can't see any difference, except that the exception is used in a procedure and not a trigger. Is that the problem? If so, how can I make this work in a trigger?

(OBS. This is just a school exercise to demonstrate error handling; DBMS_OUTPUT is probably not useful in this context, but that's not relevant for this exercise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is as you mentioned in a comment. The ORA-01400 is raised by the `insert`, after the `before` trigger has fired and completed. If that wasn't the case, you wouldn't be able to set non-nullable columns automatically from a trigger - for example, setting a primary key value from a sequence (mimicking an autoincrement ID), as you are doing to set `cust_id`.  No exception is being raised within the PL/SQL block attached to the trigger.

You could check each not-nullable column manually and explicitly within the trigger, and raise your own exception if any are null, but you'd really just be duplicating the built-in functionality. And that assumes you keep track of the column definitions - if you change the nullability of a column, you'd have to remember to update the trigger to match, unless you figured put the columns to check dynamically at run-time - which would be tricky at best, if it's possible at all (with `dbms_sql`).

If your assignment doesn't actually require this custom handling, it seems like a lot of effort for no real gain. Oracle [recommend you don't use triggers when you can use constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#CIHCEBAE); I know this is an exercise but even so, it's not something you're ever likely to want to do.

---

One way to force an run-time error in the trigger you showed is to manipulate the sequence so you try to exceed its `MAXVALUE`:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (cust_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR2(20));

CREATE SEQUENCE pk_cust_seq MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 3 NOCYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_cust_id
BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT pk_cust_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.CUST_ID FROM DUAL;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Unable to create cust_id.');
        RAISE;
END;
/
```

Then the first three inserts would work, and the fourth would fail:

```
set serveroutput on
insert into customer(name) values ('Customer 1')

1 rows inserted.

insert into customer(name) values ('Customer 2')

1 rows inserted.

insert into customer(name) values ('Customer 3')

1 rows inserted.

insert into customer(name) values ('Customer 4')

Error starting at line : 24 in command -
insert into customer(name) values ('Customer 4')
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-08004: sequence PK_CUST_SEQ.NEXTVAL exceeds MAXVALUE and cannot be instantiated
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.UPDATE_CUST_ID", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCHEMA.UPDATE_CUST_ID'
08004. 00000 -  "sequence %s.NEXTVAL %s %sVALUE and cannot be instantiated"
*Cause:    instantiating NEXTVAL would violate one of MAX/MINVALUE
*Action:   alter the sequence so that a new value can be requested
Unable to create cust_id.
```

You already have the sequence, so in your case you could `alter sequence` to cap `maxvalue` just above whatever your current highest value it, and make sure `nocycle` is set; then cause the error, and reset it to a high value after you've done your test.

Also, just as an aside, if you're on 11g you have two ways to assign the sequence number to the column; before 11g you had to do it as you've shown:

```
SELECT pk_cust_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.CUST_ID FROM DUAL;
```

... but now you can do:

```
:NEW.CUST_ID := pk_cust_seq.NEXTVAL;
```

Comment: Thanks for all the information. In fact, the assignment only specifies that all my PL/SQL should do error handling. Checking for incorrect null values was the only thing that came to my mind in relation to these triggers. Based on our conclusions, the only error handling I could come up with here would be in the getting a value from the sequence and inserting it in the cust_id field, however I can't think of what might go wrong there. I guess I'll just add a generic error handling for OTHERS that says 'Unable to create cust_id'.

Comment: @PrincessLilly - you can absolutely have an exception handler in the trigger, but it can only ever catch an exception raised within that block (or something it calls). You could force an exception, but only by adding extra code to the trigger for that purpose - try to set the ID from a string, fake a numeric or date issue, etc. Catching `WHEN OTHERS` is generally frowned on, but at least you are re-raising the error; you still lose information from the error stack.

Comment: Yes I agree that catching `WHEN OTHERS` is not the best error handling you can think of, but adding code to the trigger on purpose wouldn't give me many marks either. Error handling is supposed to fix problems due to circumstances outside of the block (the way I see it) and not something we caused on purpose :) I've had another idea, perhaps I'll handle the possibility that, for some reason, the sequence doesn't exist (could have been deleted by mistake). That sounds cooler than `WHEN OTHERS`.

Comment: @PrincessLilly - but if the sequence doesn't exist then the trigger won't compile; you'll get an error on insert but that will not be from the exception block. Unless you assign it via dynamic SQL, which would be a hack too. Maybe you can set the `maxvalue` of the sequence to a low value, and set `no cycle` - that should get a run-time exception when you try to exceed the max value on insert?

Comment: Nah, no point setting up the sequence in the wrong way. The purpose is to be able to account for actual errors that might happen even if we setup the system properly. So `OTHERS` it is :) I'm sure it won't affect my marks much. Thanks for pointing out the above about the trigger not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It should be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_cust_id
BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT pk_cust_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.CUST_ID FROM DUAL;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
     IF (SQLCODE=01040) THEN   
       RAISE my_exceptions.insert_null_into_notnull;
    ELSE
       RAISE;
  END;

EXCEPTION
 WHEN my_exceptions.insert_null_into_notnull THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Attempted to insert a null value into not nullable column.');
   RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. Same issue happens. Besides, you are also not closing your "if" statement ;-). I'm thinking the issue is that the error is being created by the INSERT itself and not by the action performed by the trigger (which in itself does not perform the insert)